# How to call a column based subset of a data.table without it automatically sorting the rows?

Tags: r, data.table

When I try to call a column based subset of a `data.table` it automatically sort the rows, any idea on how to avoid that ?

```
a=data.table(v1=rep(c(-1,0,1),3), v2=rep(c(-1,0,1),3))
head(a)
   v1 v2
1: -1 -1
2:  0  0
3:  1  1
4: -1 -1
5:  0  0
6:  1  1
head(a[,v1,v2])
   v2 v1
1: -1 -1
2: -1 -1
3: -1 -1
4:  0  0
5:  0  0
6:  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
head(a[,.(v2,v1)])
#   v2 v1
#1: -1 -1
#2:  0  0
#3:  1  1
#4: -1 -1
#5:  0  0
#6:  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

What you were doing is not a subset of columns.

```
a[, v1, v2]
```

equals to:

```
a[, j = v1, by = v2]
```

Instead you want to do this:

```
a[, j = .(v1, v2)]
```

or omitting the `j`:

```
a[, .(v1, v2)]
```